# JdbcTemplate not working with Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

and I'm using jdk8 and working on a SpringBoot project.  I'm getting "JdbcTemplate cannot be resolved to a type" I tried to maven->update project,after updating the project,I'm getting error in @Repository annotation and asking to update the JDKto1.5. The error in JdbcTemplate have gone but not able use any methods using its reference.Kindly help!

```
package com.boot.rest.repository;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.boot.rest.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<String> getUSerNames(){

        List<String> userlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        userlist.addAll(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("Select username from user"));

        return userlist;


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to import JdbcTemplate. Also, you need to make sure that you have the Spring Data jar on the classpath. Do you have it imported in the POM?

Comment: did you import JdbcTemplate? `import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;`

Comment: Your are going to provide more information?  Did you declare a template on the app context or elsewhere? 
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>

Comment: These are the dependencies I have added in pom.xml spring-boot-starter-parent,spring-boot-starter-web,spring-boot-starter-test,spring-boot-starter-jdbc,mysql-connector-java. I'm not sure if Spring data jar is part of any of these added dependencies.

Comment: @DirkDeyne , It is not letting me to import jdbctemplate , since it says JdbcTemplate cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @RobertMoskal - no i did not delcare in app coontext, I'm trying to autowire in repository class.

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: @Sharmila  RE: 'It is not letting me to import jdbctemplate' then add `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` in your pom

Comment: Do you have an app.properties file with the database settings?  What happens when you start up the app (show us the console output).

Comment: @DirkDeyne -  I have updated the pom.xml with spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc, but still it is not working. I just found that jdbcTemplate is from  org.springframework.core package. when i write import statement with for this core package. I don't see the jdbctemplate init.

Comment: @RobertMoskal - Yes I have application properties file with url,driver,uername n password.  Now all my classes are getting error including main class so when I run the application, I'm getting an error with main thread .

Answer (score 0):

QueryForList return `List<Map<String,Object>>` not `List<String>` . Spring throw exception because you handle wrong type. Here example :

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-
```

And `https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/`